# Detected resolved migration not applied to database on flyway

Tags: database, flyway

We are using flyway to manage database schema version and we are facing a problem. Since we work as a team and use git as our source code management, there would be some cases that different people update database schema on their own local repo. If that happens, we will get

> Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 2016.03.17.16.46"

The time "2016.03.17.16.46" was added by another person and I have already applied some timestamp later than that time. If that happens, we have to clean all database tables and create them again. We have tried to set false on `validateOnMigrate` and did [`flywayClean`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/clean), but nothing help. Is there another way to change that?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The migration option [`outOfOrder`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate#outOfOrder) is your friend here. Set it to true to allow inserting those migrations after the fact.

On the command line, run:

```
flyway -outOfOrder=true migrate
```

Or if you use the Maven plugin:

```
mvn -Dflyway.outOfOrder=true flyway:migrate
```

Comment: how to do that in action?

Comment: `flyway -outOfOrder=true migrate`

Comment: Note that not all migrations can be executed out of order. For instance, creating table 'foo' and adding column 'bar' to table 'foo'.

Comment: `-Dflyway.outOfOrder=true`

Answer (score 42):

I faced similar problem when switching from one git branch to another and tried to run
`flyway:migrate`.
For example when I was on branch 'release_4.6.0' I didn't have migrations on my local machine from branch 'release_4.7.0' so
I received next error
`FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally`.
The solution that worked for me is to set `ignoreMissingMigrations` flyway option to true.
In maven it looks like

```
flyway:migrate -Dflyway.ignoreMissingMigrations=true
```

Maybe it's not an answer for this question, but it can be helpful for those who faced the same problem as me.

Here you can find more details:
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/ignoreMissingMigrations

Comment: Worked for me, but looks like there is some conceptual difference in how migration work in other frameworks and in flyway.

Comment: Looks like this config parameter has been deprecated and is going to be replaced with `ignoreMigrationPatterns` in the most recent versions of Flyway (see doc here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/ignoreMigrationPatterns). Some of the functionality will only be available in the paid version Flyway Teams.

Answer (score 13):

You can also put it in your `application.properties` file if you want to apply the migrations when starting up the app:

```
spring.flyway.out-of-order=true
```

Answer (score 11):

just add `spring.flyway.ignore-missing-migrations=true`
to your properties file if you are using spring-boot.

This will ignore previous migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Since `spring.flyway.ignore-missing-migrations=true` became deprecated.
According to [the docs](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/ignore-migration-patterns-184127507.html) I advise using `spring.flyway.ignore-migration-patterns=*:missing`. Or in the yaml:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    ignore-migration-patterns:
      - "*:missing"
```

Answer (score 1):

`outOfOrder` did not fix the problem for us. 
Two migrations slipped into one deployment before it got removed.
So we added those migrations back in and undid the changes in another migration. 
Worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just renamed my migration file to some other name and then renamed it back – just to update modification date of the file. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was existing a row with version 319 in database and the correponding file for 319 was renamed do 330, so the database registry could not find the corresponding file. Deleting the row from database solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using spring, the `spring.flyway.out-of-order=true` has been deprecated. You'll have to use the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayConfigurationCustomizer` like e.g.:

```java
public class FlywayConfiguration implements FlywayConfigurationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(FluentConfiguration configuration) {
        configuration
            .ignoreMigrationPatterns(
                "*:missing", //ignore applied database migrations missing in classpath with version number < latest migration
                "*:future" //ignore applied database migrations missing in classpath with version number > latest migration 
            )
            .outOfOrder(true);
    }
}
```