# Flyway validation failed exception with an error Detected resolved migration not applied to database

Tags: java, mysql, database-migration, flyway

I have a Flyway SQL script called **V3__test.sql** and i have separated DDL and DML statements into two files called **V3.1__test_create.sql** and **V3.1.1__test_insert.sql**. Since Flyway schema history table has an entry of old file **V3__test.sql**. I am getting an exception org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed
with an error
Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 3.1

I have added config spring.flyway.ignore-missing-migrations: true into application.yml but doesnt seem working.
Flyway version 6 and cant disable migration validation because of requirement.

Exception Stacktrace:

```
    Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5a021cb9' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5a021cb9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: 
Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 3.1
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detected resolved migration not applied to database on flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077766/detected-resolved-migration-not-applied-to-database-on-flyway)